# Automatically Add Network Adapters to Bridge

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bridge

I've been using WSL 2 with a Windows Insider build. I've managed to get around some networking and systemd issues by creating a network bridge with my Wi-Fi adapter and the WSL network adapter and [genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) along with setting a [static IP](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/) to WSL, adding Cloudflare DNS servers to `/etc/resolv.conf`, and setting `generateResolvConf = false` in `/etc/wsl.conf`.

Anyways, I have an issue where the WSL network adapter is not present when WSL is not running. So when it is not running, the adapter is not a part of the network bridge. But when it does start running, it is still not a part of the network bridge. So my question is this: **Is there a way to automatically add the WSL network adapter to the network bridge?**

As a side note, I am open to solutions that involve some form of scripting, whether it be Python, Batch, VBScript, or PowerShell.

Comment: The WSL2 network adapter is automatically created and attached to a virtual switch by LxssManager service. It can not be done manually by any means and may break connection if settings are changed forcefully.